# как OleObject.Document заменить на WebBrowser1.ControlInterface.Document

Tags: delphi

```
for i := 0 to WebBrowser1.OleObject.links.Length - 1 do
      begin
        s := WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.links.Item(i).InnerText;
        if name = s then
        begin
       WebBrowser1.OleObject.document.all.tags('A').item(i).click;
        end;
      end;
```

при OleObject.Document  возникает утечка памяти рекомендуют её решать с помощью ControlInterface.Document - как им пользоваться?

Comment: Да точно так же. ControlInterface.Document возвращает IDispatch, т.е. компилятор "съест" всё, что из его методов вы попробуете вызвать. И разбираться что правильно, а что нет будет уже в runtime.

Comment: не совсем понял как использовать ControlInterface